# MySQL & PHP PDO: Data avoidance advise

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to code a coin inventory for collectors.
Now the thing is that I have an entry for each coin like

`COUNTRY  YEAR  MINT  VALUE  DESCRIPTION   COMMENT
 DE       2000   A      5       PRISTINE        OK
 FR       2018          5       PRISTINE        OK
 FR       2016          10      GOOD            OK
 DE       2018   A      5       PRISTINE        OK 
 DE       2018   D     10       GOOD            OK
 DE       2018   D     50       GOOD            OK
 DE       2018   F     100      BAD        REPLACE`

Now for displaying the coins, it makes more sense to show all coins from a single year next to each other (so you can see which coins you do have in stock, and those you don't (just a simplified example, the goal is to have much more information at each entry besides the shown N (for none), OK and REPL (replace).

Example for all coins from country DE with the year 2018:

`COUNTRY  YEAR  MINT  1c 2c 5c 10c 20c 50c 100c  200c
 DE       2018    A   N  N  OK  N   N   N   N     N
 DE       2018    D   N  N  N   OK  N   OK  N     N
 DE       2018    F   N  N  N   N   N   N   REPL  N`

I am concerned about data minimization in my MySQL database and I am asking

**Is this the right way to store that kind of data?**

I am asking because I have some trouble finding an elegant way of building a query that will give me the lower result from the upper database table, and I am suspecting it has something to do with the way I have organized my data,

Thank you for your time. Please note that I am not primarily interested in a coding example for a MySQL query but I simply want to know whether the way of storing my data is a "correct" or feasible one.

Comment: "Now for displaying the coins, it makes more sense to show all coins from a single year next to each other" Maybe.. Think off making a SQL that needs to count the coins in year 2018 for germany now with your column approach..

Comment: "I am asking because I have some trouble finding an elegant way of building a query that will give me the lower result from the upper database table, and I am suspecting it has something to do with the way I have organized my data," what do you mean with "lower result" please create a ascii data table with expected results based on the example data.

Comment: At the database structure level, think normalization.  Any field that can only have certain values should be in another table and linked via foreign keys.  Ex. countries.  You put DE, someone might put Denmak, another one DENMARK.  To avoid that you create a country table with only valid values and link that to your coins table.  This applies to other columns where you need to ensure consistency in the values.

Comment: For your lower result, lower on what field?  Year?  Value?  Combination?  SQL does provide MIN, MAX, AVG, ... and others to extract values.